# I can't read all the numbers in a .txt

Tags: java, bufferedreader, filereader

I´m trying to average a file that contains 10 millions of numbers, there is one number per line. i created a method called getAverage() that returns a double. This is the code:

```
public double promedioDouble() throws IOException
    {
        double adder = 0;
        int counter = 0;
        try{
                file = new FileReader(filePath);
                reader = new BufferedReader(file);
                while(reader.readLine()!=null)
                {
                    adder+=Double.parseDouble(reader.readLine());
                    counter++;
                }

            }
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
              System.out.println("cant read");
        }
        finally {
            if (file != null) file.close();
        }             
        return adder/counter;
    }
```

I made a print of the counter and it showed me 5.000.000, i dont know why the reader cant read the 10 millions number contained in the file and it only reads half. I need help with this.

Comment: Did you try printing the `IOException e` if there are any error occurred?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're calling `readLine` twice - and ignoring the lines that are returned within the `while` condition.

Try instead :

```
            String line;
            while( (line = reader.readLine()) !=null)
            {
                adder+=Double.parseDouble(line);
                counter++;
            }
```

You could also do this with Streams (and try-with-resources - avoiding need for `finally`) :

```
    try (Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(Paths.get(fileName))) 
    {
        stream.forEach(s -> {adder+=Double.parseDouble(s); counter++;});

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answers, I would never have imagined that was the problem I thought that  ReadLine() (within the if) only evaluated and then the action of adding was done on the same line that I had already evaluated.

Answer (score 2):

My answer's a bit far from your question. In case you're using Java 8, you can quickly do this way below:

```
try (Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(Paths.get(fileName))) {

        return stream.mapToDouble(Double::parseDouble)
                .average()
                .getAsDouble();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
}
```